# TypeError: 'BilFile' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, envi, hyperspectral-sensor

I want to use Python and Spectral library to open a hyperspectral image as ENVI file (.hdr + .dat), rewrite some bands and then save the file in the same format. I have problem with this:

> "TypeError: 'BipFile' object does not support item assignment"

I've got this response when I want to rewrite the band or change the file. Do you know of some solution or advice which could help?

```
#open file 
src = envi.open("C:\soubory_pix\SASI_1.pix.hdr", "C:\soubory_pix\SASI_1.pix")
src_band = src
#rewrite band
src_band[:, 0:319, 96] = src[:, 0:319, 96] * koef_men

#Result 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'BipFile' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: Why are you using a .pix versus perhaps a .int, when you use the `envi.open`?

Answer (score 1):

finaly I find out solution. If you have similar problem, you can load imaage to memmap like this. Then you can work with ENVI file and for saving just delete variable.

```
src = envi.open(filename_hdr)
img = src.open_memmap(writable=True)
del(img)
del(src)
```